# How to get value in key => value pair form this function

Tags: jquery

I am converting Json object to array using

```
var ticks= {firstkey: "firstvalue", secondkey: "secondvalue", thirdkey: "thirdValue"}

    var arr = $.map(ticks, function(value, index) {
                            return [[index,value]];
                        });
```

getting output as

> 0: ["firstkey", "firstvalue"] 1:["secondkey", "secondvalue"]
>   2:["thirdkey", "thirdValue"]

My desired result

> FirstKey : FirstValue SecondKey : SecondValue ThirdKey : ThirdValue

In associative array form

Comment: Please [edit] and include matching initialization code for the `ticks` variable.

Comment: You can't do this with `map()` ... `map()` always generates an array... and what you are trying to achieve is an object. The only way is to manually rewrite the array to an object.

Comment: @PeterB updated the question

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar -- The desired and original object are same. Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: now I don't understand... your object is exactly in desired format before mapping

Comment: @FlashThunder my main motive to convert the ticks json to associative array , how to do that ?

Comment: but associative array is an object in javascript... you won't get it any better... why do you want to change it to array? you can use it like an array

Comment: @31piy My ticks object is json object and i want to convert it to an array in jquery

Comment: without doing anything with it `ticks['firstkey']` would return `firstvalue` ... as I said before... associative array IS an object in javascript

Comment: @FlashThunder i want to iterate the the object and create a dynamic form it using js ex  $.each(ticks, function (key, value) {
                        Frominput+= '<input

Comment: There are no JSON objects, only javascript objects. JSON is always text in a file or in a variable, which after parsing becomes a javascript object. And you already start with a javascript object. No need to map!

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar and you CAN do that without changing the format... ->> http://jsfiddle.net/7Lj604gn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the object and push to an array accordingly. Hope this helps

```js
var ticks= {firstkey: "firstvalue", secondkey: "secondvalue", thirdkey: "thirdValue"};

var arr = Array();

for (var tick in ticks) {
arr.push({[tick]:ticks[tick]});
}

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[2].thirdkey);
```